# Derivation of the derivative of a function from $f: \mathbb {R}(n\times m) \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, matrices, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus

As I know about the derivations of derivatives, it turns out that derivatives are usually derived from the first-order Taylor expansion, concretely, $f(X + h) = f(X) + Dd(X)$ where $D$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $X$. But in this case, $f(X)$ is a scalar while $Dd(X)$ seems to be a matrix. Can anybody show me the appropriate Taylor expansion for this case or correct me if I'm wrong ? Thanks for help

Comment: A partial derivative $\mathbb{R}^{nm} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined the same way as any usual partial derivative. You can assemble all of the partial derivatives at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{nm}$ into a matrix (here a $1 \times nm$ vector) $D_x$ and express $f$ as a Taylor series around $x$ using $D_x$ as the linear term.

Comment: There's more than one kind of product used in matrix algebra, e.g. Hadamard, Kronecker, Frobenius. In this case you need to use the Frobenius product, i.e. $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$ to produce a scalar result $$f(X+dX)=f(X) + \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\bigg):dX$$